# Is segment addition a postulate or a definition?

Tags: geometry

I’m reading Modern Geometry by Dolciani from 1965. There is no mention of the segment addition postulate, but they do name a definition with the usual given statement of the segment addition postulate seen in newer geometry textbooks. My question is, is the statement for segment addition a definition or postulate?

[image]

Comment: *segment* is a defined term and the addition of segments is [Axiom III.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_axioms#III._Congruence)

Comment: They imbed the concept of segment addition into the definition of betweenness though. There is no mention of segment addition postulate in this book.